# how to delete firebase with tableView cell SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am trying to delete a test post I made on firebase using siwft but the code that I am using deletes ALL of the posts and I am only wanting to delete 1 post that was selected. In the picture below I am wanting to delete where the red arrow is pointing to specifically.

This code shows how it stores to Firebase.

```
guard let prof = uServe.currentUserProfile else {return}

    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()

    let pObj = [
        "author": [

            "uid": prof.uid,
            "name": prof.name,
            "photo": prof.photo.absoluteString

              ],
      "text": textView.text,
            "timestamp": [".sv":"timestamp"]
        ] as [String:Any]
```

[image: want to delete the red arrow, not the whole posts library]

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {



if editingStyle == .delete {
self.theposts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
    Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId().removeValue()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question won't actually remove anything from the posts node.

```
Database.database().reference().child("posts").child("uid").removeValue()
                                                     ^^^^^
```

there is no child node that's has a key of the literal string "uid"

If there were a child node with a key of "uid", only that child would be removed. For example.

```
posts
   post_0
      author: "test_0"
   post_1
      author: "test_1"
   uid
      author: "test_2"
   post_2
      author: "test_3"
```

If the structure looked like that and the code was run, it would remove the node that had a key of "uid"

```
posts
   post_0
      author: "test_0"
   post_1
      author: "test_1"
   post_2
      author: "test_3"
```

EDIT:

Supposed I wanted to delete the post_1 node from posts. Here's how that would be done (there are other ways as well)

```
Database.database().reference().child("posts").child("post_1").removeValue()
```

**EDIT 2: the good stuff**

Based on comments, the actual issue is the OP doesn't know how to get to the specific node they want to delete. Here are two options

1) Query for the node (not recommended)
With this option, you would need to query for the node by some value. The key here is the value must exist within the node. So in my above structure query for the node where author = "test_1". The downside of this is there could be multiple authors "test_1" so this option has limitations

2) Recommended
Change your Swift model to also store the node key. It's not outlined in the question but typically a tableView is backed by a dataSource, an array, and that array contains models which match your Firebase data.

I'm addressing this at a high level with pseudo-code as there's not enough code in the question know specifics.

In this case it appears to be a listing of posts so a model would be

```
class PostClass {
   var post_id = ""
   var post_text = ""
   var author_uid = ""
   var photo_url = ""
}
```

then the dataSource array to store it

```
var postsArray = [PostClass]()
```

then when Firebase is read, create the object and store the key along with the data in each object

```
postsNode.observe.... { snapshot in
   let post = PostClass()
   post.post_id = snapshot.key  //<-  this is the important part
   post.post_text = snapshot.childSnapshot("post_text") as? String ?? "No Text"
....
   self.postArray.append(post)
}
```

So now all of the data from each node is stored and when it comes time to delete, just read that object from the dataSource, get the post_id and delete

```
let post = self.postArray[index of row to delete]
let postId = post.post_id

Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(postId).removeValue()
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that they are arranged with a childByAutoID(). I have added the way the code stores in the information in the question if you could see please.

Comment: @UsmaanMahmood Thank you, I understood that from the structure. My answer still addresses the core issue in that you are attempting to delete a node with a key of the literal string *"uid"* and that node does not exist. Even if it did (as shown in my answer) it would not delete the other nodes - it would only delete the one with the key of the string: *"uid"*

Comment: So is there another way to do it?

Comment: @UsmaanMahmood Another way to do what? You're attempting to delete a node that doesn't exist. If you want to delete a specific node, you need to use the key of the node you want to delete. I added an Edit to my answer, take a look.

Comment: I understood what you’re saying and putting uid clearly won’t work. What I’m asking is what code can I use instead m so that I can select the id created by the childAutoId for a specific post? Because of what you stayed in that I wouldn’t be able to do it unless I had a specific child Name for that post. Is what I have edited closer to achieving what I wanted to achieve?

Comment: @UsmaanMahmood i understand. See Edit 2 in my answer for some high-level discussion.

Comment: Done! Thanks, Do you have an android? Because I recently released a game and it would be great if you could give it a play :).